# How do I detect the browser viewport to display desired content above the fold?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, media-queries

My problem is that I want specific content of my website to display above the fold on different viewport or screen resolutions. Is this done with Javascript/jQuery (is there a script that automatically does this?) that detects the browser viewport width and height or is it done through media queries?

I have an example of a website that does this:

http://www.themeskingdom.com/

No matter what screen size or viewport the user has, their desired content always appears above the fold. I want to accomplish the same sort of thing. Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: On that site the first section's height is set based on the browser window's height (`$(window).height();`). The navigation category icons are set to sit at the bottom of that sections using `position: absolute; bottom: 0;`. You'll have to post the code you've tried before you can get more help.

Comment: On a side note, this can also be accomplished with pure css.

Comment: @Joe I haven't begun trying to code it out because I wasn't sure where to begin...whether to accomplish it with CSS or JS. I obviously have the HTML markup with the div I want to be above the fold, but no CSS or JS manipulating it yet.I can add the HTML here in a moment.

Comment: @JoshPowell any examples or answers would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: This is a slideshow script I made, http://jsfiddle.net/Josh_Powell/FuGH5/20/show/, this is a website I am working on, http://chatfielddrilling.com/Chatfield%20V2/index.php (This could be pure css but css `calc()` does not have good mobile support and due to this site being responsive it was a bad idea), and here is a jsfiddle I just made: http://jsfiddle.net/3T2hy/show/.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a pure css solution.

By using :

```
html, body {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
```

Allows you to assign a `height: 100%;` to elements because they can base it off of the parent.

**Strong recommendations**, make sure to look into css `calc()` and `box-sizing` to make life a lot easier when working with percents.

`box-sizing` allows the padding, margin, border to all be calced inside of the tag and not outside of it.

CSS `calc()` like so, `height: calc(100% - 70px);`, is also a great tool to use but does not have the best mobile support. (calc should really only be used when you are mixing percents with pixel sizes)

This is the html:

```
<div class="mainCont">
    <div class="mainHeader">

    </div>
    <div class="control">

    </div>
</div>
```

Here is the css:

```
html, body {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

.mainCont {
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}

.mainHeader {
    width: 100%;
    height: 75%;
    background-image: url("http://www2.ca.uky.edu/forestry/maehrbearky/Forest%20trail.jpg");
    background-size: cover;
    background-position: center center;
}

.control {
    position: relative;
    height: 25%;
    width: 100%;
    background: tan;
}
```

Finally, a fiddle: [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/3T2hy/2/show)

Comment: I'm currently looking at your JSFiddle right now, and I am still a bit confused. Yes, this does take the viewport above the fold for any size screen or device, but it still takes up 100% of the content width area, or body. What if I wanted to put a div below that? I tried making a class of '.control-2' and positioning it relatively below '.control', but it's just obscured by the tan '.control' div. because the divs you made take up 100% of the page.

Comment: This is being caused by the position: absolute; which I actually did not need to use. Here you go, http://jsfiddle.net/3T2hy/1/show/. You also can have each main section take up 100% of the viewport like so, http://jsfiddle.net/3T2hy/4/show/.

Comment: @KevinStachura Any other questions pertaining any of this info?

Comment: no, your CSS solution seems to work very well. Thank you very much for your time, I appreciate it immensely!

Answer (score 0):

Simply use a div that is has background-color: transparent, and "border-bottom: 1px solid gray" and put your content in it.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but I'm interested in the intro div being above the fold, not a the sticky nav. In the example I provided, the slider content and the icons always appear above the fold, despite the user's screen resolution or browser viewport size. That's what I'm trying to accomplish. making sure my intro div stays above the fold despite the viewport or browser size.

Comment: Ok, but if I understand properly, when you say the fold, you talk about the border-bottom of the header div ?

Answer (score 0):

I would go the [media-queries](http://css-tricks.com/css-media-queries/) way, and focus firstly on `width`. But if you must take `height` in consideration, you could use either `media-queries` or `JavaScript` to detect height, though `JavaScript` might be preferable in some cases (considering browser support, like IE7 and IE8).

```
@media (min-height: 640px) { ... }
@media (max-height: 640px) { ... }
```

I created this little snippet to load JS conditionally, but it might prove useful in other applications:

```
// calculate viewport width so that we can load js conditionally
function responsive(){
    var scaffolding = 'desktop';
    var w = parseInt($(window).innerWidth(), 10);
    if (w > 0 && w < 768) { scaffolding = 'phone'; }
    if (w >= 768 && w <= 980) { scaffolding = 'tablet'; }
    if (w > 980) { scaffolding = 'desktop'; }
    return scaffolding;
}

if ( responsive() == phone) {
    // do stuff only on phones
}
if ( responsive() != phone) {
    // do stuff everywhere else but phones
}
```

An important concept behind keeping stuff on screen regardless of resolution, is that one may do it with positioning (which might involve positioned parents) or by taking away elements that are not prioritized on small viewports - letting the important elements stay. This can be done with simple media-queries, that either show or hide certain elements depending on resolution.